# How Swipe down image and show url of image in array ? (react-native-image-viewer)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how get url or index of image in array,and show console.log(index or url of image) when use onSwipeDown props in module react-native-image-viewer . thanks!
https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like the library doesn't provide an API for the above functionality. So it looks like you're going to have to maintain a state to store the currently selected index using `onChange` prop of the component, and when `onSwipeDown` is called, get the index ( and the URL ) from the state.

```
import { Modal } from 'react-native';
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

const images = [{
    url: 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/7970947?v=3&s=460',
}, {
    url: 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/7970947?v=3&s=460'
}, {
    url: 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/7970947?v=3&s=460'
}]

export default class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (index) =>  {
    this.setState({ currentIndex: index })
  }
  handleSwipeDown = (index) =>  {
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    const { url } = images[currentIndex];
    // do whatever
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal visible={true} transparent={true}>
                <ImageViewer
                imageUrls={images}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onSwipeDown={this.handleSwipeDown}
                />
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

See [docs](https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-viewer#props). Hope this helps.